# Delete all records in table first then insert new records in table Wordpress SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to develop a custom plugin using object oriented programming. I want to check if table already have values first if table have values then delete all values in table and reset ID into Zero. After that I want to install new records in to the table in wordpress. How to do that in wordpress query? Could you please help me?

This is my insert code: before insert I need to check table have values if table have values I want to delete all values in that table after delete I need to insert new data into table.

```
foreach($wc_reviews as $wc_review){
      echo $post_id =  $wc_review->comment_post_ID;
        $customer_name = get_comment_author($wc_review);
        $location = "Test";

        $description = get_comment_text($wc_review);
        $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id,'full');
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'review_data';

       $wpdb->insert( 
            $table_name, 
            array( 
                'customer_name' => $customer_name, 
                'location' => $location, 
                'image' => $featured_img_url, 
                'description' => $description, 
                'time' => current_time('mysql'), 
            ) 
        );
    }
```

Comment: what have you tried? show some code

Comment: I insert data into database using wp-cron job function.each cron job run I want to insert data into database but before that i want to delete old data in the database.

Comment: I updated my question with code please check

Comment: What's the point of 'checking '?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the table is empty or not by using `select` query:

```
$list = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM tablename)
```

If table is empty `$list` will be an empty array. If it returns any data you can truncate the table and ID will reset to 0.

```
$wpdb->query('TRUNCATE TABLE tablename')
```

After this you can do insertion.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete all rows and reset id. then you should execute this query

```
Truncate table yourTableName
```

As per WordPress documentation you can check table is exist or not

```
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
```

Comment: sorry i want to check if that table is empty or not